# Scroll to <a> on page load

Tags: scroll

I have a div with an un-ordered navigation list in it. The div it is in has a set height and the overflow set to auto to give me a scroll bar. What I want is to have the "current" navigation link scrolled to the top of the div on page load. Each list items has the class 'current-menu-item' when current. Here is what the code looks like.

```
<div class="menu-portfolio-container">
<ul id="menu-portfolio" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-174" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-174 has-image">
<a href="http://dnb.khcreativemedia.com/hinton/">
</li>
```

Here is the jQuery I tried.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.current-menu-item').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
</script>
```

Here's the link to jQuery in the head:

```
<script src="http://dnb.khcreativemedia.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1" type="text/javascript">
```

Can anyone tell me what I would need to do to get this working? This is a wordpress site using the genesis framework.

Comment: What is happening as-is? Errors?  End up at the wrong scroll location? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks. New at this and learning as I go. I see I'm getting an error "TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$(document).ready(function () {" in firebug. The code I listed is what I tried. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to actually link to jquery itself. You'll need a script tag with the SRC set to where the jquery js file is on your site(or to the online version if you so prefer) See the first example here: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: If you are getting that error about $ it isn't loading right. Likely that means the path has a problem. Try directly going to that path, and also try using a tool like fiddler to see why it isn't loading.

Comment: Going directly to the path works. Other jquery on the page works. I'll use fiddle to try and figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Does the other jquery on the page use the $ syntax? If jQuery is loaded in no conflict mode it will not alias itself as $, causing that error as well. Try jQuery() instead of $()

Comment: I have added it to fiddle and still not getting it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/KHCreative/2rn7otax/. My other jquery does not use the $ syntax, so I change this to match. Still same results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your js fiddle worked fine for me once I added jQuery for the library. Since your head isn't there you have to add it to make it work. But ya, it scrolled down just like it should

Comment: You are correct, I see it working in jsfiddle as well. I'm sure to figure it out from here. Thanks for all your help Tim. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I thought I had it. For some reason my scroll always scrolls to the bottom. I've updated the js fiddle with the exact html and css and it seems my div is scrolling to the right spot but the page is scrolling as well. If you reduce the results window to a size with scroll, you can see what I'm talking about.  I'm thinking these two combined scrolls are causing my problem. Not sure. @Tim do you have any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/KHCreative/2rn7otax/21/ Thanks. –  Keith Higginbotham 7 hours ago

Comment: Yup, looks like you have a DIV that is also scrolling, causing you headaches. Change your pageRight style to be height and width of 100% as opposed to fixed values, and it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/2rn7otax/22/

Comment: I need the set width, as it floats next to another div. I did go ahead and try the set width and height to see if it worked, and it didn't. I'll keep doing some trial and era.

Comment: OK. Use the developer tools on your browser to visualize the size of your different elements as what is happening is that you have more content than can fit into a fixed size, which causes overflow, and the overflow causes multiple items to scroll. Playing with the dom in the developer tools helps make it obvious quickly

Comment: OK, I'll give it a shot. Learning as I go. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh the agony of defeat. 3 hours later and still haven't figure this out. I've tried changing the height on all parent divs without affecting the layout. Any possible suggestions?

Comment: Tim, I still can't figure this out. Willing to pay someone who can if your interested. Just need an estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim's help, I've got it working. You can check the js fiddle page to see it in action. jsfiddle.net/KHCreative/2rn7otax

Thanks again for your help Tim.